# playframework delete object with self refering object fails

Tags: playframework, model, playframework-1.x

I have strange problem with deleting an object. I'm using Play Framework 1.2.5 and PostgreSQL Version 9.1.

I have the following two Models:

1)

```
@Entity
public class CarCollection extends Model {
    @Required
    public String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "carCollection")
    public List<Car> cars;
}
```

2)

```
@Entity
public class Car extends Model {
    @Required
    public String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Car> copies = new ArrayList<Car>();

    @ManyToOne
    public Car parent;
}
```

So, in my case I can have Cars but can copy them and then I save, that e.g. Car number 2 is copied from Car number 1 so, Car number 2 has parent = Car 1. But they are in **different** Car Collections, that's the important thing now!

Now I want to delete one CarCollection, which has the entity (car number 1) included. But as I wrote, the car number 1 is still referenced by car number 2 object as a parent.
What happens now? I would expect this CarCollection will be deleted with car number 1 and in entity with car number 2 the parent value will be null (reference deleted).
Out of the box it doesn't work! What happens? both car's will be deleted. But that's not what I expect or wanted to have.

So I decided to solve this issue with overwriting both delete() methods as follow:

```
@Entity
public class CarCollection extends Model {
    @Override
    public CarCollection delete() {
    //delete cars manually
    for(Car car: this.cars){
        car.delete();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Car extends Model {
    @Override
    public Car delete() {
    //delete parents from copied cars
    for (Car car : this.copies) {
        car.parent = null;
        car.save();
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. Doesn't matter what I try. Even if I "refresh()" my CarCollection after this delete things, won't help me too.

So, how can I solve this problem? Maybe I have a wrong Model-Definition or dependency defintition?!

Answer (score 1):

There is two things involved when you delete some entities :

- cascade definition define in your database when you create your foreign keys
- cascade definition in your jpa annotations

In your example, the 'copies' relation have a cascade all annotation. So if car2 is in the 'copies' list of 'car1' it will be deleted transitively.

If you want to break the relation by hand by overriding the delete method, you have to do it in both ways. In your case, you do not remove the child from the copies list when you set parent to null.